# Differences among string comparisons in python, c++, c# and java

Tags: java, c#, python, c++, string

It seems that string comparison cannot simply be done by "==" operator as I read from explanation that in java and c#:

In Java I saw this explanation:

```
== tests for reference equality (whether they are the same object).
.equals() tests for value equality (whether they are logically "equal").
```

In c# I saw this code:

```
if (parametrii[0].Equals("teach"))// to check the equality of values
```

It makes sense to me that "==" is checking of addresses and .equal() is just checking values.

However I have been using "==" in python and c++ all the time and I have never encounter such errors for examples

In python:

```
string1 = "helloworld"
string2 = "helloworld"

print(string1 == string2)// result true
```

In c++:

```
while(getline(ifs, line2)){
        stringstream ssm(line2);
        string from_stop;
        string to_stop;
        getline(ssm, from_stop, ',');
        getline(ssm, to_stop, ',');
        if(from_stop == to_stop){
            adjList[from_stop].push_back(to_stop);
            }
        }
```

or

```
            bool stop124 = false;
            bool stopA24 = false;
            bool stop126 = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < adjVec.size(); i++) {
                if (adjVec[i] == "124") stop124 = true;
                else if (adjVec[i] == "A24") stopA24 = true;
                else if (adjVec[i] == "126") stop126 = true;
            }
```

Those code will successfully compile and get the correct results of comparing value. I know there is a strcmp() function in c++ but I rarely use it and don't quite know when to use it rather than == in checking whether two strings are equal in value.

So my question is that is this because there is a difference among those programming languages or it is just for me to be lucky that I did not run into those errors?

Comment: who says `==` checks for reference equality? that's not always the case. (at least not in c#)

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary The quote is in reference to Java, where it's true.

Comment: If you want to know what `==` does, when comparing strings, in different languages, look up the documentation for that operator in each language.  They all explain exactly what it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Java does not allow operator overloading, they had to resort to creating a function (`Equals`) to compare for 'true' objects equality - and leave operator `==` to perform pointer comparison. This choice can not be really justified by any other reason, as it warrants for illogical code, more typing in generalized case (people usually compare for true equality, not pointer equality) and steeper learning curve.

C++ with a clear distinction between pointer and an object is not constraint by Java limitations, and thus allows proper value-semantics for classes and intuitive forms of comparison.

Comment: As usual, would venerable downvoter explain their reasons?

Comment: I voted up, it helped me with the understanding, appreciated.

Comment: About the drive-by downvote - Option 1. You are dissing Java, someone might not like that. Option 2. When scrolling on a touch screen, you can sometimes accidentally hit the voting button. Probably this causes an equal distribution of accidental up- and downvotes, but nobody asks about random upvotes.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Python compares string lexicographically i.e using ASCII value of the characters, so you can use the `==` operator. Java creates a string object, and thus you have to use the `.equals()` method to check the value.

So to answer you questions it's the language that are different. If you are trying to compare 2 strings in C++ I'd use the `compare` method.

Comment: That helps me a lot, can you show me some simple example in c++ when == give you error and std::string::compare() works?

Comment: == won't give you an error. It will return a bool value depending on the strings. Using the compare method will give you greater insight into how the strings are different. I'd suggest you do some research on how C++ works :)